# Executar Action Post por JQuery ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Gostaria de deletar um registro em um click de botão por Jquery, qual a melhor forma de realizar ? Do jeito que fiz não está funcionando.

> Action que quero chamar pelo Jquery

```
        // POST: Pais/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Pais pais = db.Paises.Find(id);
            pais.Delete();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

> Evento no Jquery onde quero chamar a Action DeleteConfirmed

```
 $('.btnExcluirSimPopover').on('click', function () {
    if (handlePopover > 0) {
      $.post("/Pais/DeleteConfirmed", { id: handlePopover }, function (data){

      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Está dando erro ou algo do tipo? consegue relatar melhor?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto, nenhum erro amigo, apenas não entra na action que estou dando o post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O data annotation `ActionName` está sobrescrevendo o nome da sua action `DeleteConfirmed` para `Delete`. Troque esse nome na sua chamada que deverá funcionar.

```
 $('.btnExcluirSimPopover').on('click', function () {
    if (handlePopover > 0) {
      $.post("/Pais/Delete", { id: handlePopover }, function (data){

      });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, mas também tive que tirar o [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], funcionou.

Comment: É verdade. Para funcionar com o `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` você precisa enviar o token gerado pelo `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` na sua request também!

Comment: Se a resposta tiver te atendido, sinalize-a como correta por favor.